# Mapreduce error with parquet format

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, parquet

I'm trying to run `mapreduce` job. My files are in a `parquet` format.

**I'm getting the following error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/TException
at parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadateConverter.readParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadateConverter.java:268)
at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:271)
at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readSummeryFile(ParquetFileReader.java:200)
at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readAllFootersInParallelUsingSummeryFiles(ParquetFileReader.java:99)
at parquet.hadoop.ParquetInputFormat.getFooters(ParquetInputFormat.java:354)
at parquet.hadoop.ParquetInputFormat.getFooters(ParquetInputFormat.java:339)
at parquet.hadoop.ParquetInputFormat.getSplits(ParquetInputFormat.java:246)
...
```

I tried to add the jar that contains the `TException` with `--libjars my_path/libthrift-0.9.0.jar` and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try setting the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` parameter to point to a `libthrift.jar` file that matches the version you need.

For example:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/var/lib/hdfs/libthrift-0.9.jar
```

Hope this helps!